# Load Databind DropDownList inside ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listviewitem

I have a ListView control that contains a DropDownList control inside the `ItemTemplate` tag.
I am trying to load the existing list items to the DropDownList using the codes below inside the `ItemCommand` event of the ListView control:

```
DropDownList ddlItem = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlItem");

con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Items";
SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
ddlItem.DataSouce = data;
ddlItem.DataTextField = "Name";
ddlItem.DataValueField = "ID";
ddlItem.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

After binding the items, I want to choose the selected items based from the database records.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You should do that in the `LIstView`'s `ItemDataBound` event. You will find your `DropDownList` there via `e.Item.FindControl("ddlItem")`. You will get the underlying datasource for that item via `e.Item.DataItem`. Use the debugger if you're unsure about the types.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Please put your comment as the answer. Resolved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should do that in the `ListView'`s `ItemDataBound` event instead. You will find your `DropDownList` there via `e.Item.FindControl("ddlItem")` get the underlying datasource for that item via `e.Item.DataItem`. Use the debugger if you're unsure about the types.

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        DropDownList ddlItem = (DropDownList) e.Item.FindControl("ddlItem");
        var rowView = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
        int id = (int)rowView["ID"];  // whatever
        // get data from id ...
        //ddlItem.DataSouce = data;
        //ddlItem.DataTextField = "Name";
        //ddlItem.DataValueField = "ID";
        //ddlItem.DataBind();
    }
}
```